# How to: Animation (triple dot) on progress bar during working macro

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar

I have a progress bar, which is showing progress in percentage and on 'animated' rectangle.

[image: progress bar]

I know how to show the progress of the macro based on "marks" in code, that's not the case. Example of code called as that "mark" in code to change the percentage on progress bar:

```
Sub progress(pctCompl As Long)

 Progression.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
 Progression.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

 DoEvents 'update the userform

End Sub
```

I wonder if it's possible to do additional animation behind "Please wait" on that progress bar - triple dot:1 dot, 1 second pause, 2 dots, 1 second pause, 3 dots, 1 second pause. This is 1 loop for that animation.

I was trying to do something, mostly I was achieving infinite loops or macro doing nothing but that triple dot animation, which was freezing Excel application.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Do Until Progression.Bar.Width = 200
    Progression.Text2.Caption = "Please wait."
    Progression.Repaint
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Progression.Text2.Caption = "Please wait.."
    Progression.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Progression.Text2.Caption = "Please wait..."
    Progression.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop

End Sub
```

I thought it is good place to ask that kind of questions - is it possible and if yes how to achieve that?

Comment: In your loop you are not increasing the width, it is making an infinite loop for the text. There should be one `Progression.Bar.Width = Progresion.Bar.Width +1`

Comment: Please try using timer

Comment: Freezing, because your do loop will not stop, and your other process Will not run except the do loop

Comment: Or you can add doevents in your do loop, it Will help but not as an answer, I think.

Comment: @David García Bodego that was totally not the case, I know how to deal with progress bar.

Comment: @user11982798 I knew this is useful function, but to launch macro module every exact of time, not during work of other macro... or I don't really know the range of this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes have an image that I like to 'animate' on a `UserForm` as a progress indicator, and I use the Win API timer for that. The code below may be a little 'overkill' for your needs, as image changes need to be triggered either by an event or by `Repaint`, the latter of which can cause flicker. I believe `Labels` update as soon as the property value changes. If this is the case then you could leave out the listener class shown below and adjust the code accordingly.

With the above caveat, a skeleton implementation could look like this:

**Userform code**

*Note: my userform has a start button, a stop button and one label, called lblWait.*

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mTimerListener As cTimerListener

Private Sub btnStart_Click()
    HandleStartTimer mTimerListener
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click()
    HandleStopTimer
End Sub

Private Sub mTimerListener_DotCountIncremented(count As Long)
    Me.lblWait = "Please wait" & String(count, ".")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mTimerListener = New cTimerListener
End Sub
```

**Class code**

*Note: I've called this class cTimerListener.*

```
Option Explicit

Public Event DotCountIncremented(count As Long)

Private mDotCount As Long

Public Property Let DotCount(RHS As Long)
    mDotCount = RHS
    If mDotCount > 3 Then mDotCount = 0
    RaiseEvent DotCountIncremented(mDotCount)
    DoEvents
End Property

Public Property Get DotCount() As Long
    DotCount = mDotCount
End Property
```

**And Module code**

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, _
        ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

#Else
    Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal HWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, _
        ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal HWnd As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
#End If

Private mTimerId As Long
Private mTimerListener As cTimerListener

Public Sub HandleStartTimer(timerListener As cTimerListener)
    Set mTimerListener = timerListener
    #If VBA7 Then
        mTimerId = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 0.5 * 1000, AddressOf TimerProc64)
    #Else
        mTimerId = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 0.5 * 1000, AddressOf TimerProc32)
    #End If
End Sub

Public Sub HandleStopTimer()
    KillTimer 0&, mTimerId
End Sub

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Sub TimerProc64(ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

        TimerProc
    End Sub
#Else
    Private Sub TimerProc32(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

        TimerProc
    End Sub
#End If

Private Sub TimerProc()
    If Not mTimerListener Is Nothing Then
        With mTimerListener
            .DotCount = .DotCount + 1
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: At the beginning I was struggling a little bit to fit that to my progress bar, also I'm not really familiar with Classes. Now I can clearly see that I need to learn about them. @Ambie , hats off. It is working. Maybe it has small issue with repainting (when numbers of progress increase slowly - repaints bar slowly), but I think it is significantly small problem comparing to the job You did with this code. Offtopic: do You have any recommended links to learn about Classes?

Comment: @Teamothy. Yes, classes become pretty important if you want to go into more complex VBA solutions. You could just google VBA classes tutorial, as there are loads on the web. From memory, there's a decent one from Chip Pearson.

Comment: Maybe it is "temporary", but now it is not working, @Ambie . It was working earlier, cause my 'progress' bar was refreshing that userform (calling sub every loop to put iteration numbers to bar). Unfortunately doing any code in background (for example 2 loops filling cells in sheet) causing progress bar, only based on your code, to freeze. `DoEvents` or `UserForm.Repaint` is not working for that. Don't really know how to deal with that.

Comment: You'll need to post another question. Remember to include all your associated code so we can have a good look at it.